# ORDER BY clause displaying numbers in output

Tags: php, mysql, output

I have a query that uses an ORDER BY clause in it.

This is potentially causing the output display numerical values, instead of the textual output as desired.

**My question** : What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to output the `Ed_Name` , `GroupName` fields from my query and it is outputting what appears to be like a single character from a database entry.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the backticks from your `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Sadly I removed the backticks, but that didnt change anything

Comment: So why not just proper JOINS ?

Comment: Sidenote: seriously look into the naming of things...

Comment: @RichardBernards - edited. All- I added my function there, is there something completely wrong with it that isn't getting the info into the function?

Comment: Not exactly what I meant with naming things properly. Try reading up on: http://deviq.com/naming-things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are looking for resides in `$paths['Ed_Name']` and `$paths['GroupName']`.

The values you see are the first characters of every column in your query.

**3**3, **3**, **5**, **c**hanging occupation, **E**ducation, **h**igh school diploma or GED, **4**

That happens because you loop through the columns and then try to output `$job['GroupName']`, where `$job` is in fact a string, hence it is first converting `'GroupName'` to integer, which produces 0, and then gives you that first character.